# code prints incorrect output in in jupyter notebook whereas it is running correctly on online IDE

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

```
# Program for Armstrong Number
# this program prints wrong results in jupyter but running correct in online ide

import math
print("this program is for armstrong number\n")
m=0
p=0
n=int(input("Enter any number: \n"))
y=n
while y!=0:
    y=y/10
    p+=1
y=n
while n!=0:
    x=n%10
    m+=math.pow(x,p)
    n=n/10
if y==m:
    print("The given number is an armstrong number\n")
else:
    print("The given number is not an armstrong number\n")
```

Comment: I know about indentation in python and i use it here

Comment: could you improve the question by including the error that the code is generating and any steps you have taken to debug it so far? The chances of useful responses increases with a more descriptive question.

Comment: Works for me. Include what input you used and what error you get.

Comment: my input is 371 and output i get is the statement written in else block of my code on my jupyter notebook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use integer division, rather than "/". Replace `y=y/10` and `n=n/10` with `y=y//10` and `n=n//10`.

Using `/` for integer division **might** work - if you happen to be running Python 2. In Python 3, `/` is regular (mathematical) division and 11/10 = 1.1 (**not** 1). Note that the integer division operator `//` works both in Python2 and Python3, always use that if you want integer division.